# Getting PHPStorm to indent correctly when pressing enter inside a statement?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, indentation, auto-indent

I have this code for example:

```
$sql = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE {{%users}} SET foo=:foo, bar=:bar");
```

Now if I go in and put my cursor just before `SET` and press enter, PHPStorm will place the code at the *start* of the next line. Is there anyway to get it to indent so it goes under the `UPDATE` or similar automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "Continuation indent".

You can set this parameter in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> (the language you want) -> Tabs and Indents -> Continuation Indent (set to number of spaces you want)

Comment: Well I don't want to set the amount of spaces, it should be something like a *smart indent*.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't fully understand your problem, sorry. Try out "Align when multiline" for "Method call arguments".

It's in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> (Your Language) -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method Call Arguments -> Align when multiline

Comment: I tried that out with the PHP code style, but no luck. Couldn't find anything like that for `SQL`.